# Simpleperf doesn't unwind stack

Tags: performance, android-ndk, profiling

I'm attempting profile an Android NDK 14b clang based application with Google's [simpleperf](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/extras/+/master/simpleperf/) sampling profiler. The recorded callstack samples aren't actually unwound -- just the top frame of the callstack seems to be recorded, so the profiling reports aren't very useful. I've specified -fno-omit-frame-pointer in most of the code, but this seems to make no difference.

What am I missing? Is there a more current profiler for Android NDK projects I should be using?

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing frame pointer based unwinding (using --call-graph fp option), please use aarch64 architecture, because arm has combined arm/thumb code, and can't unwind well even if you use -fno-omit-frame-pointer everywhere.

If you are doing dwarf based unwinding (using -g or --call-graph dwarf option), -fno-omit-frame-pointer doesn't work, and you'd better use shared libraries containing debug info in the apk.

It is also possible that the unwinding stops at java code. To unwind java code, you need to fully compiled it into native code and use dwarf based unwinding.

After all, you can use app_profiler.py contained in the ndk r14b. It tries to handle details for you, fully compiling the java code, and downloading libraries with debug info to device. It is also easy to check and change if it doesn't work well in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

There are some simpleperf options I've found I need to specify (or not specify) which seem to make it more likely that I get the expected call-graph.
If I specify '-a --cpu 1' for instance, then the binary I'm profiling won't even appear in the call graph.
For instance if I do (where perf_text.x mostly spins for 1 second on cpu 1):

```
simpleperf record -g -a -e cpu-cycles --cpu 1 ./perf_test.x -C 1 -w bw -t 1
simpleperf report -g caller
```

then perf_test.x won't appear at all (for me) in the output.
So drop the --cpu x option if you are using it.
Also, high sampling rate increases the overhead. Below runs with the (current) default sampling rate of 4000 sample/sec.

```
simpleperf record -g -a -e cpu-cycles -F 4000 ./perf_test.x -C 1 -w bw -t 1
simpleperf report -g caller
```

Above shows simpleperf as the top process using 40-70% of the samples.
Reducing the sampling rate:

```
simpleperf record -g -a -e cpu-cycles -F 1000 ./perf_test.x -C 1 -w bw -t 1
simpleperf report -g caller
```

brought perf_test.x up to the top % of total samples and the 1st simpleperf entry comes in at 24% of total samples.
Hope this is helpful.